# How to upload large file in express with progress bar?

Tags: node.js, upload, express, progress-bar

Currently I am using `socket.io` to upload the video with progress bar. Here is the tutorial

> http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-create-a-resumable-video-uploade-in-node-js/

but Internet Explorer does not support this method, but I really need upload the video in all browsers.

I checked the express documentation. Since express is based on `node-formidable` (which has a progress event), I think there is way to build a upload system with progress bar, right? I just don't know how!

Is node-formidable IE enabled right?

Any way is it possible to build a file upload system in pure espress.js with progress bar?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with the xhr.upload progress event. It is supported from html5.

For example:
https://github.com/zeMirco/express-upload-progress

In php the upload information can be attached to the session, so it works with html4, maybe there is a nodejs extension for that too, I'll google it.

According to this:
[How to do upload with express in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028036/how-to-do-upload-with-express-in-node-js)
there is a progress event in express by file upload, so you can set a variable in the session with the actual progress data, and read it with ajax from client side.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/harshgupta0227/pk67g28k/) using angular js and [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload#spring) directive.

The jsfiddle works for images and files but to upload the videos you will have change the POST url to your server.

```js
//inject angular file upload directives and services.
var app = angular.module('fileUpload', ['ngFileUpload']);

app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'Upload', '$timeout', function($scope, Upload, $timeout) {
  $scope.uploadFiles = function(file, errFiles) {
    $scope.f = file;
    $scope.errFile = errFiles && errFiles[0];
    if (file) {
      file.upload = Upload.upload({
        url: 'https://angular-file-upload-cors-srv.appspot.com/upload',
        data: {
          file: file
        }
      });

      file.upload.then(function(response) {
        $timeout(function() {
          file.result = response.data;
        });
      }, function(response) {
        if (response.status > 0)
          $scope.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
      }, function(evt) {
        file.progress = Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 *
          evt.loaded / evt.total));
      });
    }
  }
}]);
```

```css
.thumb {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  float: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 7px;
}

form .progress {
  line-height: 15px;
}

.progress {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  border: 3px groove #CCC;
}

.progress div {
  font-size: smaller;
  background: orange;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://angular-file-upload.appspot.com/js/ng-file-upload-shim.js"></script>
<script src="https://angular-file-upload.appspot.com/js/ng-file-upload.js"></script>


<body ng-app="fileUpload" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <h4>Upload on file select</h4>
  <button type="file" ngf-select="uploadFiles($file, $invalidFiles)"  ngf-max-height="1000" ngf-max-size="100MB">
    Select File</button>
  <br>
  <br> File:
  <div style="font:smaller">{{f.name}} {{errFile.name}} {{errFile.$error}} {{errFile.$errorParam}}
    <span class="progress" ng-show="f.progress >= 0">
          <div style="width:{{f.progress}}%"  
               ng-bind="f.progress + '%'"></div>
      </span>
  </div>
  {{errorMsg}}
</body>
```