# Server sided file upload percentage sharing nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

Imagine an online service that lets two browser-users share files between them, using a session key string to communicate simply with HTTP pulls through the server as the middle-man, not websocket.

For better user experience, it would be a nice idea showing the file receiver user the currently uploading files & their progress from the uploader.

**So how I thought to do that and where did I have an issue?**

Firstly, when a file is going to be uploaded - the client will send the server the file metadata as in Size, Name, etc

But then, how would I create the progress bar of the upload on the file receiver's end? I would need a websocket connection and send the progress  on the uploader's end, but that's not ideal, isn't it?

I would like to ask if it is possible in Express.js, to catch have a listener inside of the route for the file upload, to fire an event everytime a chunk of data is uploaded, so then i can update the database that stores the information that both ends (receiver, uploader) needs to get when they do an HTTP Pull to update the state.

Answer (score 1):

First, you'll need to capture incoming request progress. You may use [formidable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable) with express to listen to [progress](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable#progress) event. See example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14034047/3290062).

You may store file's progress in a database, so the receiver would see currently uploading files.

Note 1: This is a huge overhead having multiple db writes per single upload. Memory caching would be preferable for single instance servers or databases.

Note 2: With pulls, receiver only sees the file's progress on load. This might be solved with periodic pulls, say 1s interval, which seems "live enough", but that would bring much more overhead. Websockets are recommended for live progress updates.